# Do onlick functions wait for promises?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, onclick, synchronization

I've been doing some coding in JS today. I essentially have a server that returns an output as a promise.

Consider essentially the following code:

```
let reviewData = [];
db.get()
  .then(function (snap) {
    snap.forEach(function (doc) {
      reviewData.push(doc.data());
      console.log(reviewData[0]); //this works
    });
});
console.log(reviewData[0]); //this does not work here
```

When I try to access reviewData outside of this code, it comes up as empty. However, when I access review data, inside the then function, it's there.

This makes sense because the db.get() returns a promise, that is resolved.

Additionally, I had a button on my webpage that executes a function on click.

```
<button onclick="doThis()">Click</button> //this code is in the html document
function doThis() {
   console.log(reviewData[0]); //this works? Why?
}
```

My only question is that how come when an onclick function is triggered, the data from the promise is visible? Does the onclick function wait for the reviewData to be pushed?

All of the script code is in one external document.

Comment: `db.get()` is asynchronous and won't have completed before the first log....but certainly will have completed before you trigger the event. No the `onclick` does not wait for promises....it's just that it resolved on it's own long before you click the button

Comment: @charlietfl So basically, it just happens that in my code here, that the db.get() is completed. It doesn't have anything to do with the onclick function waiting for the db.get() right? For example, if I removed the onclick function and just called doThis(), would it potentially just give me nothing?

Comment: That is correct ..

Comment: @charlietfl Okay, that's good to know. I need to do some refactoring then, this is a dangerous case lol.

Comment: Also my comments are based on no connection or other request errors. In ideal conditions that request would completely in well under a second and it takes longer than that probably for you to see and click the button

Comment: @charlietfl I don't access this resource again, other than these instances. And I don't have other errors, so I think it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is asynchronous. The order of action is as follows:
        1. `let reviewData = [];`
        2. `db.get()`
        3. `console.log(reviewData[0])` (nothing now)
        4. `function (snap) {
            snap.forEach(function (doc) {
            reviewData.push(doc.data());
            console.log(reviewData[0]);
           })}}`
        5. `function doThis() {
           console.log(reviewData[0]);}`